# What to use for wrapping connect function only in react-redux apps?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Do I need to use HOC if I only need to change mapDispatchToProps and mapStateToProps but not change the presentational component?
For example:

```
export class SomeContainer extends Component {...}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
 //IMPORT HERE STATE
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
 ...someFn,
 //IMPORT HERE OTHER DISPATCH FN
});
```

And reuse it in other components by changing connectFn.

I just wrapped it up in different components

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from "react";
import SomeContainer from "./index";

export class ReuseSomeContainerA extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <SomeContainer {...this.props}/>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
    //...customDispatchsA
});

export const enhance = connect(() => state => ({
    //customPropsA
}), mapDispatchToProps);
export default enhance(ReuseSomeContainerA );
```

And likewise with another used SomeContainer

```
export class ReuseSomeContainerB extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <SomeContainer {...this.props}/>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
    //...customDispatchsB
});

export const enhance = connect(() => state => ({
    //customPropsB
}), mapDispatchToProps);
export default enhance(ReuseSomeContainerB);
```

In addition to these functions do not change anything.
Is there a way of more correct composition mapDispatchToProps and mapStateToProps only?

Comment: Have you tried to use reselect's structured selectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you would need to wrap anything in these ReuseSomeContainer components.

As I understand the question, you have the component `SomeContainer` which expects some props (values and functions) from redux. You want those values and functions to be different in different parts of your app, but `SomeContainer` would do the same thing everywhere.

You would just export SomeContainer and the use it in different locations.

Component A:

```
const ConnectedContainerA = connect(mapStateToPropsA, mapDispatchToPropsA)(SomeContainer);
```

Component B:

```
const ConnectedContainerB = connect(mapStateToPropsB, mapDispatchToPropsB)(SomeContainer);
```

Comment: Yes, almost so, but I need to change only 1 property in mapDispatchToProps. Should I export mapStateToProps from SomeContainer and merge mapDispatchToProps with mapDispatchToProps SomeContainer?

Comment: One thing you could do is to connect SomeContainer to redux with the params that are always the same in all parts of the app. Then export the connected component. In places where you use it, wrap it again with connect, this time with only the params that are different.

This adds an extra redux connection, but unless you're running a lot of these components and need to be extra careful with performance, that should not be a problem.